# Microsoft account permanently suspended - access to OneDrive data?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-account

A child of mine has had unauthorized activity on their Microsoft account (the validation email got changed by malicious actors). We contacted Microsoft support, and unfortunately,

> The only option we have is to permanently suspend this account to prevent any further use. At this time, I have successfully suspended this account, and this will remain on indefinitely.

So now we can't log on to the account any more, and can't access anything connected to it.

Now, the child has not been using OneDrive, but stores everything locally. Which got me thinking:

*If a Microsoft account is permanently suspended, do you also lose access to all OneDrive data that is not right now on the physical machine? If so, is there anything one can do?*

The only info on this I could find is [this MS answers thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-account-got-locked-is-there-a-way-to/50cdb7cf-bd25-4096-8cdb-92bc6b45aa69), but I would appreciate independent confirmation. Right now, I am looking at getting external hard drives and teaching my family to make regular on-site backups... which kind of defeats the entire purpose of the cloud and OneDrive.

Comment: Also, I find it remarkable that someone can change the validation email address on a MS Family account without the administrator even being notified, much less having to sign off on this.

Comment: Perhaps another example of security theatre vs. actual security?

Comment: OneDrive or anny cloud storage isn’t a backup solution. It’s cloud storage. You still need local backups of your important files

Comment: One may only beg Microsoft Support for data access.

Comment: "If a Microsoft account is permanently suspended, do you also lose access to all OneDrive data that is not right now on the physical machine?" Yes.  "If so, is there anything one can do?" Contact Microsoft... but don't expect much help. As others state, when you give all your data to a third party to hold, and have no local copy, you've created a new point of failure. Consider Google Drive issue, as well: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/245055606/google-drive-files-suddenly-disappeared-the-drive-literally-went-back-to-condition-in-may-2023?hl=en

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: thank you, I think that is as much of an answer as I am likely to get. Do you want to post your comment as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, "If a Microsoft account is permanently suspended, do you also lose access to all OneDrive data that is not right now on the physical machine?" Yes.

"If so, is there anything one can do?" Contact [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us)... but don't expect immediate help.

As others have stated, when you give all your data to a third party to hold, and have no local copy, you've created a new point of failure. Consider a recent [Google Drive issue](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/245055606/google-drive-files-suddenly-disappeared-the-drive-literally-went-back-to-condition-in-may-2023?hl=en), as well: users did *nothing* wrong yet accounts appear to have lost months of data. Consider keeping disk images locally, as well as storing data in the cloud. There are a number of tools, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/?license=free).